# Understanding the Gram-Schmidt Procedure and Its Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation, inner-products, gram-schmidt

In Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielson and Chaung, the Gram-Schmidt procedure is defined as: given that we have basis $w_1,...,w_d$ for some vector space $V$, we can construct an orthonormal basis set $v_1,...,v_d$ for V by inductively defining

$$
v_{k+1} = \frac{w_{k+1} - \sum^k_{i=1}\langle w_{k+1}, v_i\rangle \cdot v_i}{||w_{k+1} - \sum^k_{i=1}\langle w_{k+1}, v_i\rangle \cdot v_i||}
$$

To further understand why this works, I found a proof online [which can be found here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-gram-schmidt-process). It uses proof by induction. Assuming that we have shown that the base case works, if we have $j > 1$, then we can define a set of vectors basis $w_1,...,w_{j-1}$ and $v_1,...,v_{j-1}$. We hence define $v_j$, then

$$
v_{j} = \frac{w_{j} - \langle w_j,  v_1\rangle \cdot v_1 - \langle w_j,  v_2\rangle \cdot w_2...\langle w_j,  v_{j-1}\rangle \cdot v_{j-1}}{||w_{j} - \langle w_j,  v_1\rangle \cdot v_1 - \langle w_j,  v_2\rangle \cdot w_2...\langle w_j,  v_{j-1}\rangle \cdot v_{j-1} ||}
$$

Let $N = ||w_{j} - \langle w_j,  v_1\rangle \cdot v_1 - \langle w_j,  v_2\rangle \cdot w_2...\langle w_j,  v_{j-1}\rangle \cdot v_{j-1} ||$ and $k$ be some integer less than $j$ but greater than or equal to 1. If we take the inner product of $v_j$ and $v_k$, we get:

$$
\langle v_{j}, v_{k} \rangle = \frac{1}{N}\langle w_{j} - \langle w_j,  v_1\rangle \cdot v_1 - \langle w_j,  v_2\rangle \cdot v_2...\langle w_j,  v_{j-1}\rangle \cdot v_{j-1} , v_k \rangle
\tag 1
$$

Hence, we get:
$$
\langle v_{j}, v_{k} \rangle = \frac{1}{N}(\langle w_j, v_k \rangle - \langle w_j, v_k \rangle) = 0
\tag 2
$$

My questions are the following:

1. Why does (1) reduce down to (2)? Maybe there exists a better proof to help me to understand this...?
2. This is probably indirectly answered by the above question, but why does the subtraction $\langle w_{j}, v_i\rangle \cdot v_i$ from $w_j$ for $i \in [1,...j-1]$ produce an orthogonal vector? Is there some theorem that I am missing which explains this?

Thank you!

Comment: Use that $\langle v_i, v_k\rangle=1$ if $i=k$ and $\langle v_i, v_k\rangle=0$ if $i\neq k$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch with that, though, how do I obtain two inner products? I apologise if the question seems very basic, I just began studying this. It seems as if I should obtain $\frac{1}{N} \langle w_j, v_k \rangle$.

Comment: We have (here I am using bilinearity of the scalar product) $$N\cdot \langle v_j,v_k\rangle=\langle w_j - \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} \langle w_j, v_i\rangle\cdot v_i,v_k\rangle = \langle w_j,v_k\rangle-\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} \langle \langle w_j, v_i\rangle\cdot v_i,v_k\rangle =  \langle w_j,v_k\rangle-\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} \langle w_j, v_i\rangle \cdot \langle v_i, v_k\rangle = \langle w_j,v_k\rangle-\langle w_j,v_k\rangle$$ Don't hesitate to tell me if any equality is unclear

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch makes perfect sense, thank you very much (by the way, just saw your profile, congratulations on pursuing your Master's at such a young age, keep it up!)

Comment: Thank you for the kind words 